# limit the number of printing contents from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have an array with elements,

```
var input=[

{
    "count": 1,
    "entity": "Company",
    "Company": [
        {
            "sector": "Consumer, Cyclical",
            "ticker": "NWY",
            "entity": "New York & Co",
            "New_York_&_Co": [
                {
                    "count": 1,
                    "entity": "New York"
                }
            ],
            "type": "SCap"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "count": 1,
    "entity": "Country",
    "Country": [
        {
            "region": "North Americas",
            "index": "MEXICO IPC INDEX",
            "Mexico": [
                {
                    "count": 1,
                    "entity": "Mexico"
                }
            ],
            "entity": "Mexico",
            "currency": "Peso (MXN)"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "count": 2,
    "entity": "Persons",
    "Persons": [

        {
            "count": 1,
            "entity": "Edwin Garay"
        },

        {
            "count": 1,
            "entity": "Rosa"
        }
    ]
}];
```

I am trying to order the output of this data. I want to display the values like,

```
Company-New York & Co, Country-mexico, Persons-Edwin Garay,Rosa
```

I don't need data present in the last level... I've written a function,

```
    function generateTree(input) {  
if (input == undefined) {
    return;
}

else {

    for ( var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {

        if(entityName1!=input[i].entity)
            {


            entityName = input[i].entity;
            entityName1 = input[i].entity;
            entityName = entityName.replace(/ /g, "_");
            alert(entityName);
            }

        if (input[i][entityName] != undefined) {
            generateTreeHTML(input[i][entityName]);

        }
    }
}}
```

The above script will print the output,

```
Company-New York & Co, NewYork , Country-mexico,mexico, Persons-Edwin Garay,Rosa
```

I dont want the base levels NewYork and Mexico. How do I do that?

Comment: `"Facets": [{` is a syntax error...

Comment: I don't understand the structure of your json. The format doesn't make any sense. Why not have a simpler format?

Comment: Where are `entityName1` and `entityName` defined?

Comment: I have corrected the syntax...it was my typing error..

Comment: You still have a syntax error - you're missing a closing brace and bracket.

Comment: entityName1 and entityName  are defined outside function globally..

Comment: _Why would you define them globally?_ Why not in the function?

Comment: Yes the array has a mixture of different objects, it would surely make more sense to have them in separate variables of the same types and then parse the data like that?

Comment: defining inside the function doesnt make any difference...

Comment: Where is `generateTreeHTML` defined?

Comment: @Eric I dint get you...its in a javascript file..

Comment: When I run your code without that function, I get `Company Country Persons`.

Comment: @danrichardson this is the way I get the input... cant change it..

Comment: @Eric I ve said I need the output like Company-New York & Co, Country-mexico, Persons-Edwin Garay,Rosa

Comment: The output you say your code _does_ produce is not something I can make it produce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following produces your requested output:

```
function ​generateTree​(input) {
    var i,
        j,
        currentEntity,
        currentEntityType,
        output = "";

    for (i=0; i<input.length; i++)​ {
        if (i > 0) output += ", ";
        currentEntity = input[i];
        currentEntityType = currentEntity.entity;
        output += currentEntityType + "-";
        for (j=0; j<currentEntity[currentEntityType].length; j++){
            if (j > 0) output += ",";
            output += currentEntity[currentEntityType][j].entity;
        }
    }
    return output;
}

​alert(generateTree(input));​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7PpEY/

I've ignored all the fields you don't care about. I've ignored the fact that in your data the "Persons" object's "Count" is 10 even though there are only two people in the inner array. Your function was recursive, but I don't see any need for that.

Comment: That would depend on what you want to do with the other fields. They vary depending on the entity type, e.g., "Company" has "sector" but 
"Country" has "currency". "Company" and "Country" have inner arrays but "Persons" doesn't. The approach would depend on whether you want your code to extract the field names and/or values without understanding what they are or if you need to take specific action for the different entity types. The code I've already shown is reasonably self-explanatory, but it will quickly get messier as you introduce more requirements.

Comment: I want to extract both field names and value and display them separately... bt at the same time it should be linked to the main entity..like company.Ford should have all the fileds linked to it ..

Comment: Your current output format (with the separate entities on the same line separated by commas ) isn't very suitable for adding the extra fields. I don't have any more time tonight, but perhaps if you gave a clear example of what the output should look like? (Possibly in a new question, given this one is answered and accepted.) In any case I'm signing off for now. Good night.

Comment: u hv any clue hw I should arrange an input like that to a data structure form which should contain all the fields linked to corresponding value as I need to get the values of each fields..

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure seems overly complex to me. the `count` fields are especially useless. Can't you modify your data structure to look like this?

```
var data = {
    "companies": [{
        "name": "New York & Co",
        "sector": "Consumer, Cyclical",
        "ticker": "NWY",
        "type": "SCap"
    }],
    "countries": [{
        "name": "Mexico",
        "region": "North Americas",
        "index": "MEXICO IPC INDEX",
        "currency": "Peso (MXN)"
    }],
    "people": [
        "Gustavo",
        "Rosa"
    ]
}
```

Comment: _"I need all those fields to display"_ - I have no idea what you're trying to say

Comment: Im wrking on UI part, so thos efileds are important in one way or another... as they need to be displayed in the site

Comment: What fields? You don't mention fields anywhere in the question

Comment: count and everyother field Ive specified

Comment: I'm puzzled by what `count` represents. You have `count: 10`, yet there are only two people listed. Is this a mistake?

Comment: Ive changed the count to 2 for people... does it make sense nw?? you are going out of topic instead of concentrating on the issue..

Comment: So count is useless then. You realize javascript has a `.length` property, right? I can get count with `input[2].Persons.length`.